# React - axios - blocked by CORS policy. How to unblock

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I am running a simple API request to return data to a simple API search I've written. I say it's simple API call because there is no authentication needed and I can do it in python very simply.

However, I am having issues when using Axios in React.

Code:

```
 axios.get('https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/59554ab7-b414-4220-8514-408a0dbf572d')
```

I've tried looking here and everyone one makes it sound so simple, but I can't seem to do anything. I've tried.

```
axios.get('https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/59554ab7-b414-4220-8514-408a0dbf572d', { crossDomain: true })
```

and

```
axios.get('https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/59554ab7-b414-4220-8514-408a0dbf572d, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        },
        })
```

But I keep getting errors like
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/59554ab7-b414-4220-8514-408a0dbf572d' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

or

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Do I need to put something in the header to make this work? Or is this some kind of setting I need to make in react.

Help!

Comment: seems the website don't allow access from unknown domains

Comment: Nothing you can do except for making the request using a proxy server, i.e. your backend.

Comment: See *“How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems”* section of
the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/441757

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help and the link. As a new React.js programmer, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 13):

You just cannot override CORS check from the client side. Just cannot. CORS is security feature and there would be no sense if it were possible just to disable it.

There are different approaches.

1. Depending on your words

   > I say it's simple API call because there is no authentication needed and I can do it in python very simply.

   I believe you just need to ensure no extra headers are send so request would become [simple in meaning of CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS). Across axios site I've found several ways to drop any extra headers for specific request:

   a. either by [specifying `headers` explicitly](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/382)

   b. or by creating [different axios instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) that you will not provide with Authorization header or whatever force CORS to be run
2. making proxy to be run on your domain
3. making backend to whitelist you domain with listing it in `Access-Control-Allow- Origin` response header